# Draw a heatmap with "super big" matrix

Tags: r, heatmap, bigdata

I want to draw a heatmap.
I have 100k*100k square matrix (50Gb(csv), numbers on right-top side and other filled by 0).

I want to ask "How can I draw a heatmap with R?" with this huge dataset.
I'm trying to this code on large RAM machine.

```
d = read.table("data.csv", sep=",")
d = as.matrix(d + t(d))
heatmap(d)
```

I tried some libraries like heatmap.2(in gplots) or something.
But they are take so much time and memories.

Comment: Sorry but an heatmap of 100k x 100k tiles is totally impossible to visualize on a screen, even if it worked the image would be hugely scaled down and you'll see one interpolated pixel where there should be 50x50 tiles...so, why don't scale the matrix and then call heatmap ?

Comment: Is it meanings that I should downsampling like 10:1 rows and cols and draw?  In this case, the clusters looks like equal?

Comment: Yep, that's what I mean... alternatively you could separate your matrix in say 100 submatrices and plot each of them...

Comment: Or separate it in 1000x1000 matrices and plot averages.

Comment: @iaroslav-domin Could you show me your idea as a code? I didnt get it all.

Comment: Out of curiosity... how long does `read.table` takes ?

Comment: I don't know exactly, but It's takes about 1.5 hours to run this code and die with out of memory (128GB).

Answer (score 9):

What I suggest you is to heavily down-sample your matrix before plotting the heatmap, e.g. doing the mean of each submatrices (as suggested by @IaroslavDomin) :

```
# example of big mx 10k x 10 k
bigMx <- matrix(rnorm(10000*10000,mean=0,sd=100),10000,10000)

# here we downsample the big matrix 10k x 10k to 100x100
# by averaging each submatrix
downSampledMx <- matrix(NA,100,100)
subMxSide <- nrow(bigMx)/nrow(downSampledMx)
for(i in 1:nrow(downSampledMx)){
  rowIdxs <- ((subMxSide*(i-1)):(subMxSide*i-1))+1
  for(j in 1:ncol(downSampledMx)){
    colIdxs <- ((subMxSide*(j-1)):(subMxSide*j-1))+1
    downSampledMx[i,j] <- mean(bigMx[rowIdxs,colIdxs])
  }
}

# NA to disable the dendrograms
heatmap(downSampledMx,Rowv=NA,Colv=NA)
```

[image]

For sure with your huge matrix it will take a while to compute the downSampledMx, but it should be feasible.

---

**EDIT :**

I think downsampling should preserve recognizable "macro-patterns", e.g. see the following example :

```
# create a matrix with some recognizable pattern
set.seed(123)
bigMx <- matrix(rnorm(50*50,mean=0,sd=100),50,50)
diag(bigMx) <- max(bigMx) # set maximum value on the diagonal
# set maximum value on a circle centered on the middle
for(i in 1:nrow(bigMx)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(bigMx)){
    if(abs((i - 25)^2 + (j - 25)^2 - 10^2) <= 16)
      bigMx[i,j] <- max(bigMx)
  }
}

# plot the original heatmap
heatmap(bigMx,Rowv=NA,Colv=NA, main="original")


# function used to down sample
downSample <- function(m,newSize){
  downSampledMx <- matrix(NA,newSize,newSize)
  subMxSide <- nrow(m)/nrow(downSampledMx)
  for(i in 1:nrow(downSampledMx)){
    rowIdxs <- ((subMxSide*(i-1)):(subMxSide*i-1))+1
    for(j in 1:ncol(downSampledMx)){
      colIdxs <- ((subMxSide*(j-1)):(subMxSide*j-1))+1
      downSampledMx[i,j] <- mean(m[rowIdxs,colIdxs])
    }
  }
  return(downSampledMx)
}

# downsample x 2 and plot heatmap
downSampledMx <- downSample(bigMx,25)
heatmap(downSampledMx,Rowv=NA,Colv=NA, main="downsample x 2") 

# downsample x 5 and plot heatmap
downSampledMx <- downSample(bigMx,10)
heatmap(downSampledMx,Rowv=NA,Colv=NA, main="downsample x 5")
```

Here's the 3 heatmaps :

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you @digEmAll !! I understood clearly. By the way, Do you think the downsampled matrix shows the same properties as the original one? I'm concerned thet the properties of the matrix will be changed by downsampling (and that's why I tried to draw with original one).

Comment: Thank you for the polite commentary. When I dont need to clustering, I think what you said is correct, but is it similar if you need to do clustering after downsampling?

Comment: @kgyk1993: mmh...downsampling will "smooth" the values so I don't know if the clustering result will be the same...

Comment: @kgyk1993: don't know exactly what you need, but maybe you can create the downsampled heatmap just to have a visual idea of the values distribution, but perform a cluster analysis on the original matrix (I don't think hierarchical clustering is usable here, maybe kmeans...)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This matrix shows something like a relationship score between 100k data. And I want to know if there are clusters in the data or not. I completely do not know about them. Finally, I downsampled the matrix to ten matrixes (10k*10k), clustered (ward.D2) respectively, and drew using heatmap.2 (it takes about 5.5h each). As a result, there were heatmaps that the cluster seemed and not seemed, so there seems to be possibilities like clusters.